# Xcode 9.1 iOS simulator Window > Physical Size disabled

Tags: xcode, xcode9.1

I need to make screen shots (specifically iPad Pro 12.9") for the App Store. I resized the simulator to fit it on my mac's screen. Now I can't resize it back to 100%, which is required to make a new screen shot. Both sizing options, Physical Size (Cmd-1) and Pixel Accurate (Cmd-2) are grayed out. How do I reset the simulator back to 100%?

**Workaround:** I was able to manually resize the simulator window using the mouse to grab the corner (the new way to adjust size in 9.1). Using trial-and-error by resizing, making new screen shots, and checking the resulting pixel dimensions, I was able to manually get it back to 100% (2048x2732). The original question still remains; is there a way to reset the simulator to 100% without using this workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47173670/6137672 see this

Comment: @Leo You linked to an answer that says to turn the device to landscape, then press the Pixel Accurate setting. That doesn't work for most cases though because Pixel Accurate is still grayed out.

Comment: Recent updates to the simulator is completely bullshit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just resize up the simulator window dragging until the size reaches a size greater than or equal the original size, this worked for me.

Comment: I just tested this and it works like a charm. I resized it in my test to crazy big and the screenshot size still came out perfect, 2048x2732.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: Another workaround: unchecking "Window > Show Device Bezels" re-enables "Pixel Accurate" command.

Answer (score 20):

I could get the screen shot with resolution of (2048x2732) deactivating the option of "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale"

[image: Simulator/Debug/Optimize Rendering for Window Scale]

Comment: perfect, I removed my comment.

Answer (score 3):

The real reason why the pixel accurate size option is greyed out is because your screen resolution is too low to fit the device with that size. Solution is to increase your screen resolution temporarily under system settings > display in mac os.

Answer (score 2):

Though resizing of simulator using Cmd + 1...5 is now disable however, you can resize it by dragging simulator **with pointer** is available like any normal window on **OS X**. 
You can resize it by dragging simulator either from right or left or bottom.

Comment: That works for resizing the simulator to fit an arbitrary area on the screen. What I am looking for, however, is a way to resize it back to 100%, which is needed to make screenshots for the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

1.Close/Quit simulator

2.Xcode 9.1 >> Window >> “Devices and Simulartors” >> "Simulartors"，
then remember the device identifier you want to set

[image]

3.Then open the file

> ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator

4.Find out simulator device id you want to set

5.Set "SimulatorWindowLastScale" value = 1

[image]

Comment: This does not work. When you open the simulator again it is the same size as when it was closed. (9.2 beta)

Answer (score 2):

In xcode(mine is 9.1), uncheck Window->Show Device Brezels to make changes on simulator, then check it to make screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

**On Simulator 10.0 (Xcode 9.4.1)**

Hardware **>** Rotate Left or Rotate Right

and this will re-enable Physical Size selection (Window **>** Physical Size) if it got disabled/ grayed out

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

**Using Xcode 11 the "Optimize Rendering for window scale" is not present anymore**. Just select default simulator for **iPhone Pro Max** and make screenshot with `⌘ + S`

You will have 1242 x 2688 px screenshots saved on Desktop

Answer (score 1):

You can make it to default size by pressing the Zoom option in the simulator window option.The Zoom option will get enable when the physical size is selected.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have an Apple Thunderbolt Display, and the Simulator shrinks the window to fit the display. However, if I press Cmd+S to make the screenshot the resulting PNG still has the 100% size of 2048x2732. No need to play with bezels or corners :-)

Comment: This is the best answer as of 2018-01.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have launched the simulator and you want to get the normal size back, click the simulator, then, go to **Window**, select **scale** option, then choose the **actual size**. That will solve that.

Comment: Window->scale was in 9.0. In Xcode 9.1, the scale option has been removed. There are two reset options (I'm pretty sure they're new) that appear to address sizing, Physical Size (Cmd-1) and Pixel Accurate (Cmd-2). Both are disabled.

Comment: I am currently using xcode 9.0. I have not updated to the latest version. I thought you are using same version.